# test to use while comparing two frequencies

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

I have a column A with the following frequency distribution for all the values in that column A

```
Value      Frequency
3          292
4          71
5          47
6          62
7          22
8          12
9          22
```

I have another column B , similarly, these are the frequency distribution for all the values in that column B

```
Value      Frequency
3          274
4          71
5          46
6          62
7          22
8          12
9          22
```

Please note that the frequencies for value 3 in Column A is 292 and frequency for value 3 in column B is 274.  My goal is to find out if the frequencies for value 3 in column A is statistically different than frequency in column B for value 3.
I am guessing I cannot use Chi-Square test ? So what test should I use to test whether the frequencies for value 3 in these two columns A, B are similar or different ?

Comment: I think a  paired-sample t-test should do it. I ran it in Matlab and got that your distributions do not reject the null hypothesis at the default 5% significance level even if equal variances are not assumed. The null hypothesis is that the differences between the second columns of A and B come from a normal distribution with mean of zero and unknown variance. In other words, per this test they are statistically similar distributions.

Comment: @Such There is no pairing evident here between the 528 events summarized in column A and the 509 events in column B, so how could a paired sample t-test possibly be applied?  And what sense would it make to posit that a limited number of differences of frequencies could be Normally distributed?

Comment: Something's bothering me : if A and B are two different treatment, and you want to test if there is a difference between them, then shouldn't you have more than one "experimental unit" per treatment ? Please tell me if that's not clear enough.

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure why you say there is no pairing; the random variable [3,4,...,9] are the same between A and B. Re: "And what sense ...to posit...", if nothing changed between sampling A and B then the difference between them would be normally distributed.

Comment: @Such I believe you misunderstand what "frequency" means in this question.  Regardless, the supposition of a normal distribution is not credible: no set of seven distinct numbers will be normally distributed, or even close to it.

Comment: @whuber I wasn't talking about the seven distinct numbers being normally distributed, I was talking about the difference of their frequencies being normally distributed. Nevertheless, I agree that distinct (i.e., discreet) numbers won't be normally distributed, but they can certainly be binomial distributed, which can be approximated by a normal distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are mainly interested in the proportion of outcomes taking Value 3,
then it seems best to compare that proportion in A, which is $292/528 = 0.553,$
with that proportion in B, which is $274/509 = 0.538.$ The difference seems
quite small.

A formal test (here done in Minitab) shows that this difference
is not significant at the 5% level (P-value $0.635 > 0.05).$ Also notice
that a 95% confidence interval for the population difference covers $0$ (no
difference).

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample    X    N  Sample p
1       292  528  0.553030
2       274  509  0.538310

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.0147199
95% CI for difference:  (-0.0458945, 0.0753343)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = 0.48  P-Value = 0.634
```

This test uses a normal approximation of the difference between
two binomial proportions, which should be very accurate for your sample sizes
above 500.

*Notes:* [a] You could also do a chi-squared test of the null hypothesis that the
proportions of outcomes with Values 3 through 9 are 'homongeneous' for A and B.
(Computations are the same as for a test of 'independence' between Values (3
through 9) and Types (A and B). That test also does not give a significant result.

```
Pearson Chi-Square = 0.235, DF = 6, P-Value = 1.000
```

[b] I do not see how it would be appropriate to use a t test to answer this question.

Comment: @Bruce if you have the time, please see my comments above your answer and let me know where I am wrong to suggest a paired sample t-test. I am very curious if my logic is flawed.

Comment: I think @whuber's upvoted Comment pretty much covers what I'd say. Especially, lack of pairing of item responses (obvious from unequal sample sizes) and no basis for assuming normality for tallied counts. With data for first column in `a`, `shapiro.test(a)` returns P-value  0.001315, a surprisingly strong result for only seven numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As we are dealing with frequencies, we can use chi-square by converting the data into 2x2 table as shown below:
[image]

Chi square = 0.22   P = 0.63

You can also use proportion test. It is clear that both the sets of observations are independent.